# minicart js - add to cart opening on new tab

Tags: javascript, html, shopping-cart

I am trying to add minicart js to the website I am building but I appear to be having some issue.

With reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022762/view-paypal-shopping-cart-contents-on-my-site) question, the accepted answer links a demo which opens a mini cart GUI when the add to cart button is pressed.

However, when I inspect element and copy the exact code used in the demo into my editor and run the page, when I press add to cart, paypal opens on another page, rather than displaying the mini cart.

I have been trying different versions to see if it mattered (3.0.6 is the latest) but having the same issue.

I would just like the mini cart to display on my page.

## EDIT

I've found another post which said to remove the code protection which apparently worked for another user but unfortunately did not work for me, I'm at a loss as to why the minicart window won't display.

This is the code I am using which works for the demo but not for my page:

```
<html>
<body>

<form target="paypal" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" >
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="demo@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="test Add to Cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="12.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://www.paypaltech.com/vimal/test.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:btn_cart_LG.gif:NonHosted">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/minicart/3.0.3/minicart.min.js"></script>
<script>
    paypal.minicart.render();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working, instead of using the link provided in the documentation, I downloaded the source code instead and included the link to the minicart.js file which i put into my project structure.

Everything worked after that :)

Final code:

```
<html>
<body>

    <form target="paypal" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="demo@gmail.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="test Add to Cart">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="12.00">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://www.paypaltech.com/vimal/test.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:btn_cart_LG.gif:NonHosted">
        <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
        <img alt="" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>

    <script src="minicart.js"></script>
    <script>
        paypal.minicart.render();   
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```